# C++ Avoiding redefinition of code that needs to return a polymorphic type

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, code-organization

I have a set of classes (SubClassA, SubClassB, etc) that inherit from SuperClass. These classes have a myriad of methods that are exactly identical between the subclasses, except that they return a reference to **this* (a.k.a. SubClassX&). The return type can't be deprecated to SuperClass& either, because then the subclass-specific functions and members wouldn't be accessible.

I'm looking for a short, clean way to implement this so that I don't have to replicate the method code in each subclass.

The best thing I've been able to come up with is something like this (pseudo-code), but I'm not sure if this would even work:

```
//methods.cpp
SUBCLASS& general_method_1() {return *this;}
SUBCLASS& general_method_2() {return *this;}
```

And then:

```
#define SUBCLASS SubClassA
class SubClassA : public SuperClass
{
     #include "methods.cpp"

     SubClassA& specific_method_1() {return *this;}
}

#define SUBCLASS SubClassB
class SubClassB : public SuperClass
{
     #include "methods.cpp"

     SubClassB& specific_method_2() {return *this;}
}
```

Not to mention this seems kind of hackish and difficult to interpret. Any ideas?

EDIT: 
I should have mentioned that I will need to be able to polymorphically access the subclasses through pointers to SuperClass. For example, the following needs to be valid:

```
SuperClass* subclass[2];
subclass[0] = new SubClassA;
subclass[1] = new SubClassB;
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this ? Why dont you factorize the "myriad" of common methods in the SuperClass, returning a SuperClass reference to *this ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. The client code already needs a reference to the object to invoke the member function. They also need to know the expected return type to make any use of the returned reference to derived. As such, even if you get this to work, it appears the best you can hope for is to duplicate what `dynamic_cast` would do without your writing any code at all.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: This appears to be a case of covariant method, such as `clone`. There are a number of more or less practical solutions, including (1) C++ constructor argument forwarding to middle-man CRTP-like inheritance, (2) macro, simple but also ad-hoc, (3) dominance in virtual inheritance, ugly and complex. Oh, and for this case, possibly (4) required most derived class that adds implementation. OK, I [wrote a blog article about it](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/cppx-3-ways-to-mix-in-a-generic-cloning-implementation/) in 2010, but that's pre-C++11.

Comment: If you do decide to run with the style of solution you mention in the question, using a `typedef SubClassX This;` is better than a macro for [all the usual reasons](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-vs-macros.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRTP.

```
template <class Derived> class Base
{
    Derived& derived() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }
};

class Derived1: public Base<Derived1>
{
};

class Derived2: public Base<Derived2>
{
};
```

In order to access things polymorphically, one needs to split Base in two:

```
class Base
{
  public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    // virtual Base& derived() = 0; -- note: this will NOT work!
};

template <class Derived> class BaseImpl : public Base
{
    Derived& derived() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }
};

class Derived1: public BaseImpl<Derived1>
{
};

class Derived2: public BaseImpl<Derived2>
{
};

int main()
{
    Base* b[2] = { new Derived1, new Derived2 };
}
```

Comment: better then my version

Comment: This would be perfect except that I don't think I could access Derived1 and Derived2 through pointers to Base (see edit) :(

Comment: Then you need to split Base to a regular class and a template class, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it:

```
class Dystopia {
  using This = Dystopia;
  This& beHappy() {
    // make me happy
    return *this;
  }
};

class Utopia : public Dystopia {
  using This = Utopia;
  This& beHappy() {
    return static_cast<This&>(Dystopia::beHappy());
  }
};
```

The main point here is that when you are in a derived class you can explicitly call the base method.

Note that the typedef is just a commodity (is not required).
As a sidenode: avoid macros in C++. Can’t emphasise this enough: **Avoid macros!!**. Armageddon will come in macros and good luck then debugging the *End of the world*.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest the following:

1. Create a .h file that contains one or more macros to declare the common functions.
2. Create a .h file that contains one or more macros to define the common functions.
3. Add the include file created in (1) in the class header files and use the macro(s) to declare the functions.
4. Add the include file created in (2) in the class .cc files and the use the macro(s) to define the functions.

Example:

`DeclareFunctionsMacros.h`

```
#define DECLARE_FUNCTIONS(THIS_CLASS) \
THIS_CLASS& general_method_1();       \
THIS_CLASS& general_method_2();
```

`DefineFunctionsMacros.h`

```
#define DEFINE_FUNCTIONS(THIS_CLASS)                         \
THIS_CLASS& THIS_CLASS::general_method_1() { return *this; } \
THIS_CLASS& THIS_CLASS::general_method_2() { return *this; }
```

`SubClassA.h`

```
#include "DeclareFunctionsMacros.h"

class SubClassA : public SuperClass
{
   DECLARE_FUNCTIONS(SubClassA);  
   SubClassA& specific_method_1() {return *this;}
}
```

`SubClassA.cc`

```
#include "DefineFunctionsMacros.h"

DEFINE_FUNCTIONS(SubClassA)
```

This will allow you to alter definitions of the macros used in defining the functions without needing to recompile everything that `#include`s `SubClassA.h`.

Comment: Shouldn't `THIS_CLASS& general_method_1() { return *this; }` be `THIS_CLASS& THIS_CLASS::general_...`?  And for SubClassA.CC `#include "SubClassA.h".  Anyway, what this boils down to is a preference for macros over multiple inclusions of the same header....

Comment: @TonyD, Yes, of course. Thanks for finding the error and letting me know. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether all you require is to make use of `covariant return types` and a template.

For example:

```
class SuperClass
{
public:
    virtual SuperClass& method() = 0;
};

class SpecificA : public SuperClass
{
public:
    int specificMethodA();
};

class SpecificB : public SuperClass
{
public:
    int specificMethodB();
};

template<class Specific>
class SubClass : public Specific
{
public:

    virtual SubClass& method() { return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    SubClass<SpecificA> scA;
    SubClass<SpecificB> scB;

    scA.method().specificMethodA();
    scB.method().specificMethodB();
}
```